# Border-and-padding-only vertical bar next to field and label with Grid

Tags: css, css-grid

What would be the easiest way to show a vertical red bar next to a DIV with fields and validation messages using Grid with the same result as in the first Flex example? The bar is implemented as a DIV's left border with a padding.

It's easy with Flex: I just stack the 2 DIV's and they assume default sizes: the padding is followed, and the height is whatever the max DIV is. In the Grid example I defined `grid-template-areas: "a b";` but the default spacing doesn't work. I don't want to define widths and sizes, the bar's padding of 15px should be sufficient.

```css
.error {
  color: red;
}

.flexExample {
   display: flex;
}

.flexVerticalBar {
   border-left: 3px solid red;
   padding-left: 15px;
}

.gridExample {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "a b"
}

.gridCol1 {
   grid-area: a;
   border-left: 3px solid red;
   padding-left: 15px;
}

.gridCol2 {
   grid-area: b;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexExample">
   <div class="flexVerticalBar"></div>
   <div>
      <span class="error">Name is required</span><br/>
            <label for="textName">Name:</label><br/>
            <input type="text" id="textName" />
   </div>
</div>

<hr/>

<div class="gridExample">
   <div class="gridCol1"></div>
   <div class="gridCol2">
      <span class="error">Name is required</span><br/>
            <label for="textName">Name:</label><br/>
            <input type="text" id="textName" />   
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: justify-content: start; to the grid container

Comment: No. That will put the red bar next to the 2nd section, while leaving all the space on the left unused. You can try it.

Comment: you said : *using Grid with the same result as in the first Flex example* and that's what it does (I already tried)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the first grid column as min-content:

```css
.error {
  color: red;
}

.flexExample {
   display: flex;
}

.flexVerticalBar {
   border-left: 3px solid red;
   padding-left: 15px;
}

.gridExample {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "a b";
  grid-template-columns: min-content auto;
}

.gridCol1 {
   grid-area: a;
   border-left: 3px solid red;
   padding-left: 15px;
}

.gridCol2 {
   grid-area: b;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexExample">
   <div class="flexVerticalBar"></div>
   <div>
      <span class="error">Name is required</span><br/>
            <label for="textName">Name:</label><br/>
            <input type="text" id="textName" />
   </div>
</div>

<hr/>

<div class="gridExample">
   <div class="gridCol1"></div>
   <div class="gridCol2">
      <span class="error">Name is required</span><br/>
            <label for="textName">Name:</label><br/>
            <input type="text" id="textName" />   
   </div>
</div>
```